# VSCode Scala Metals: Mainclass not found after updating plugin from 1.23.0 to 1.24.0

Tags: visual-studio-code, build-tools, scala-metals

After updating the Scala (metals) extension in VSCode on 2023/07/20, the mainclass is not found anymore and thus cannot run anymore in a project that uses a workspace.
In a project without workspace, everything still works.

We expect this to be related to the multi-root workspace feature in the metals update, but didn't find a solution yet.

Anybody else having the same issue and a solution?
Temporary workaround seems to be reverting to 1.23.0...